# How to solidify partition wall after removing a section

Tags: drywall, walls, structural, partition

I removed a non-load-bearing (partition?) wall that was making a small closet. On each side, I removed two studs. On the top, a top plate(?) remains, which I'll remove next.

My problem is that on each side, beneath the two studs is a larger wood piece. The drywall seems attached to it. On the lefthand side, all is fine, this is a wall against the next house and it stays firmly in place. On the righthand side, though, this piece of wood is within another inside wall. It seems like it was held in place against the two studs I removed. It is not completely free to move, but it is not really solid either.

If I am to patch up the drywall, I don't feel like the righthand side will be solid enough and cracks will keep reappearing (maybe I'm just pessimistic?). Anyway, I wonder how I should go about making this more solid? Is my only option to remove the drywall, solidify it, and redo more drywall?

[image]

[image]